# How to define STUB in RTRT for C pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, rtrt

How to define STUB in RTRT for C pointer?
I am trying to test the FuncA module but pop up with an error in IBM RTRT tool,

```
void FuncA(U_INT Var1, States_T Var2)
{
    X_Data_T *DATA_2 = NULLPTR;
    Y_Data_T *DATA_1 = FuncB(Var1, &DATA_2);

    if((DATA_1 != NULLPTR) && (DATA_2!= NULLPTR))
    {
        Body;
    }
}

Y_Data_T * FuncB(U_INT Var1, X_Data_T **Var3)
{
    int K;

    if())
    {     
    }
    else
    {    
    }
    return DATA_1;
}
```

```
Stub is defined as below in the ptu script,
#Y_Data_T *Test_DATA_1;
#X_Data_T **Test_DATA_2;
#Y_Data_T * FuncB(U_INT _in Var1, X_Data_T _out **Var3);
STUB FuncB(2,&Test_DATA_2)&Test_DATA_1
```

```
Error:
TestRT attolccp: "cmingw64_Project_Eulynx\TTest.c",line 297: warning #513-D: a
       value of type "X_Data_T**" cannot be assigned to an entity
       of type "X_Data_T *"
    *Var3 = Attol_ptr_out->_dataout.Var3;
```

Note: States_T and X_Data_T are STRUCT